# Pyautogui will work until it has to input something into the interpreter, which at that point will stop until I click enter manually

Tags: python, interpreter, pyautogui

I am currently trying to create a program that lets me enter a name, and then by using pyautogui, searches up that name on my computer's message application, then asks the person who's name I typed in if they want to do the pythagorean theorem. The program copies their messages, and it is supposed to have a back and forth with the person who is being messaged and the interpreter directly. The problem I am having is that when python copies the message of my friend, it goes to paste it into an input setup in the interpreter, but will just freeze. It won't continue running until I click enter manually to bypass the input that I set up, which at that point will paste the message into the interpreter, even though the input has already been used. I tried to insert a filler input before the first input, which asks the user if they want to solve for a leg length or hypotenuse. I'm sorry if the explanation is unclear, I hope it is understood better with code. Even with a filler it doesn't work. By the way, (373, 823) is a point within the interpreter just so pyautogui clicks on the interpreter to use it.

```
pyautogui.click(373, 823)
fillerinput = input("filler: ")
pyautogui.press("a")
pyautogui.press("enter")
userchoice = input("leg or hyp: ")
time.sleep(2)
pyautogui.click(373, 823)
pyautogui.keyDown("command")
pyautogui.press("v")
pyautogui.keyUp("command")
pyautogui.press("enter")
```